# Pass Authenticator access token to web view with react-adal

Tags: reactjs, azure, adal

I have an ios app which is protected by MS authenticator app (using broker). After I acquire the token I need to pass the token to web view which loads a web site which is protected with react-adal. I tried passing the token as http://mysite/#id_token={token}. But it's prompting for sign in page again. Is there a url I can use to pass the token to react-adal ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the above question, you are able to get the access_token and id_token and you need to use that token to access web view which is protected with react-adal. 
Can you pass **access_token** in authorization header instead of id_token and validates in the react app.